# get twitter friends using my specific app

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am integrating twitter api on iphone device with specific application. I want to get list of followers using the same app.

Is it possible to get list of followers who are using the same app?

Thanks,
Jim.

Answer (score 0):

Use this api call in your twitter api to get your followers in twitter

```
- (NSString *)getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus:(BOOL)flag
```

{
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"statuses/followers.%@", API_FORMAT];

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
if (!flag) {
    [params setObject:@"true" forKey:@"lite"]; // slightly bizarre, but correct.
}

return [self _sendRequestWithMethod:nil path:path queryParameters:params body:nil 
                        requestType:MGTwitterFollowerUpdatesRequest
                       responseType:MGTwitterUsers];
```

}

Comment: I can get followers list using above method but say i have authorize X application. Now i want to get followers who are using X application. I tried with above method and regardless of flag value YES/NO, it gives same value in each cases.(It returns list of all followers).