# Get Twitter followers that has installed the same app

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitterkit

I want to get a list of followers of a user that has authorized my app via their twitter account, using the TwitterKit for iOS or their REST API. 
Similar to how facebook returns a user's friends that have the app installed on their facebook account.

I know this wasn't possible a couple of years ago. ([15075606](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075606/twitter-api-followers-that-have-also-allowed-app), [10908702](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908702/get-twitter-friends-using-my-specific-app))

But is this available today? Does anyone have a workaround?

Last option is to store the user's Twitter ID on a server and compare it with the ids that get returned when fetching a user's followers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not available in the Twitter API.